# Ker and Img of cochain Map -subcomplex -

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Show that if $\psi: A^\bullet \to B^\bullet$ is a cochain map then $\ker(\psi)$ is a sub-complex of $A^\bullet$, $\operatorname{im}(\psi)$ is a sub-complex of $B^\bullet$, and the natural map $q: A^\bullet \to \operatorname{im}(\psi)$ is a cochain map.

I know that the $\ker(\psi^n)$ is a sub-group of $A^n$  (or sub vector space)
and $\operatorname{im}(\psi^n)$ also a sub-group of $B^n$ (for all $n\geq0$) but what is the map from $\ker(\psi^n)$ to the $\ker(\psi^{n+1})$?

Comment: Use the restriction to ker$(\psi^n)$ of the map $A^n\to A^{n+1}$ given by the cochain complex $A•$.

Comment: What assures us that the Image of restriction of the map $A^n$ to $A^(n+1)$ is in $ker(ψ^(n+1)$ ?

Comment: $\psi$ is a cochain map, so it commutes with the maps in the complexes.

Comment: $ker(ψ^n)$  is sub group of $A^n$ what the homorophism in this case from $Ker(ψ^n)$ to  $Ker(ψ^(n+1))$ , sorry i don't understad wich can i use $ψ$ here ? and the if the homomrohpism is the restriction i don't understand why the image of restriction is in $Ker(ψ^(n+1))$ ?

Comment: Your last comment is difficult to parse, but it seems to be based mostly on misreading my earlier comments. In particular, you asked "wich {probably meaning why] i can use $\psi$ here". But I didn't say anything about using $\psi$. The only "use" in my comments was to use a restriction of a map from $A•$.

Comment: I understood your intention , but my problem now to be persuaded why the image of restriction is in $ker(ψ^(n+1))$ ? , thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d_A^\bullet$ and $d_B^\bullet$ denote the differentials from $A^\bullet$ and $B^\bullet$ respectively.

Showing that $\ker(\psi)$ is a cochain complex:

We claim that $d_A^\bullet$ restricted to $\ker(\psi)$ makes $\ker(\psi)$ into a cochain complex. Denote this restriction with $\partial_A^\bullet$. Consider the commutative diagram, which commutes since $\psi$ was assumed to be a cochain map:

[image: Commutative diagram]

Using the universal property of the kernel, we get existence of unique morphism $\ker(\psi^i)\to \ker(\psi^{i+1})$ marked with the dashed arrow which in fact is $\partial_A^\bullet$. This map satisfies the property $(\partial_A)^2=0$ since $(d_A)^2=0$. We have now argued that $\ker(\psi)$ is indeed a cochain complex. Furthermore, we can identify it as a subcomplex of $A^\bullet$ via the inclusion.

Showing that $\operatorname{im}(\psi)$ is a cochain complex:

Since $\psi$ is a cochain map, we get that $d_B^i\circ \psi^i=\psi^{i+1}\circ d_A^i$. It follows that
$$
\operatorname{im}(d_B^i\circ \psi^i)=\operatorname{im}(\psi^{i+1}\circ d_A^i)\subset \operatorname{im}(\psi^{i+1}).
$$
This inclusion says that $d_B^i$ restricted to $\operatorname{im}(\psi^i)$ has image in $\operatorname{im}(\psi^{i+1})$. Denote this restriction with $\delta_B^i$. This map satisfies the property $(\delta_B)^2=0$ since $(d_B)^2=0$. Thus we have shown that this makes $\operatorname{im}(\psi)$ into a cochain complex which is identified with a subcomplex of $B^\bullet$ via the inclusion. By our construction and the fact that $\psi$ is a chain map, we also get commutative diagram:

[image]

Commutativity of this diagram says that the natural map $q:A^\bullet \to \operatorname{im}(\psi)$ is a cochain map.